# Terraform Move Resource State

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have a terraform resource that does not use `count`. I updated it to use `count`. I want to make terraform state aware of the change (otherwise terraform complains that resource with same name already exists). I tried this:

```
terraform state mv 'module.users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password' 'module.users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password[0]'
```

According to [terraform's documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/v1.5.x/commands/state/mv#example-move-a-particular-instance-of-a-resource-using-count) for version 1.5.7 that I am using, this is the correct syntax, but I am getting this error:

```
│ Error: Invalid target address
│ 
│ Cannot move module.users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password to module.users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password[0]: the source is a whole resource (not a resource instance) so the target
│ must also be a whole resource.
```

The reason I want to make this change is to ensure terraform does not try to recreate this group if it exists by setting the count to 1.

Comment: I've done this many times in the past and never ran into that error. I think Terraform 1.5.x even auto-detects and auto-modifies the state for you. I'm wondering if that has already happened and your state file is already updated, based on that error message. If you run a `terraform plan` now, does it indicate that it is going to (re)create the resource, or does it indicate that the resource already exists?

Comment: Thanks. `terraform plan` returns this:
`module.airflow_rw_users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password[0] will be created`
When I run this plan, I get the error that this resource already exists which is why I was trying to move it.

Comment: It sounds like something has progressed to the point that it is too late to run a `terraform state mv` and you should simply do a `terraform import` of the resource to prevent it from trying to recreate an already existing resource.

Comment: This error suggests that Terraform thinks the previous state for this resource already had `count` or `for_each` enabled and so it can't move a multi-instance resource into a single instance of that same resource. Running `terraform show` might give a clue as to what state things are currently in.

Comment: It might still be possible to use `terraform state mv` to recover here, but you'll need to first learn what address the current state is using to track this object.

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins. `terraform show` shows: `# module.users.aws_iam_group.allow_change_password[0]:
resource "aws_iam_group" "allow_change_password" {..}` 
Also this group was created using `module.users` reference of `users` module and current plan is invoking ` module.airflow_rw_users` reference of same module, not sure if that matters?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include that additional information since that will make it easier to read and it's an important detail about your situation. With that said: the address already shows a `[0]` suffix, and so Terraform already seems to be tracking the object at the address you wanted to move it to. It seems that no further action is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using [`moved`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax) block if you still have a backup for your TF state.

e.g:

If you apply this:

```
resource "local_file" "foo" {
  content  = "A file"
  filename = "foo.txt"
}
```

Then, you add a count on the resource it would be named as `local_file.foo[0]`, so we can refactor it with `moved`:

```
resource "local_file" "foo" {
  count    = 1
  content  = "A file"
  filename = "foo.txt"
}

moved {
  from = local_file.foo
  to   = local_file.foo[0]
}
```

Then `terraform plan` would be:

```
local_file.foo[0]: Refreshing state... [id=1321d2d033b22bee1187fd1e01d8aede47676569]

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # local_file.foo has moved to local_file.foo[0]
    resource "local_file" "foo" {
        id                   = "1321d2d033b22bee1187fd1e01d8aede47676569"
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```